# Mathematical preparation for programming graphics

Tags: math, 3d, 2d

The question is addressed to those who already have experience in programming, graphics 2D or 3D. What is the mathematical background needed for the programming schedules? And how often do you have to apply this knowledge in practice?

Comment: this belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Which library/framework do you plan using?

Comment: @matijash I'm still undecided.

Comment: This is off-topic.  Nevertheless a good search for similar questions, and their answers, on SO will provide much guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't think it matters what language or framework you are using, it comes down to 3 areas you will need to consider from a background knowledge point of view.

1. Vector Math
2. Trigonometry
3. Discrete Algorithms

I'd be tempted to get a good grip on all three of these before you begin. Also, start simple - Vectors and Trig are a lot simpler in 2D, then once you get the hang of it progress to adding 3D.

Good luck, have fun!

Comment: I would also recommend basic matrix math.  No initial need for the fancy stuff, but make sure you know how matrix multiplication works, and why...